# How can i convert this content?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I get this kind of content from an API request and like to use the data in other needs, my problem is, how can i extract the informations in a way it is usable like a simple list?

```
[{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":28164,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3427,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":11082,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3330,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20494,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20495,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33078,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12305,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3417,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":22043,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":23069,"skillpoints_in_skill":3072000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3419,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":24613,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":24241,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":23594,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":19719,"skillpoints_in_skill":271530,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":20525,"skillpoints_in_skill":543059,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":20526,"skillpoints_in_skill":452549,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20530,"skillpoints_in_skill":3072000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11443,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20532,"skillpoints_in_skill":3072000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20533,"skillpoints_in_skill":3584000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":23606,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3337,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3423,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3424,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":23618,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":21059,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3335,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":2,"skill_id":3446,"skillpoints_in_skill":2829,"trained_skill_level":2},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3429,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":1,"skill_id":3340,"skillpoints_in_skill":1000,"trained_skill_level":1},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12215,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12365,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12366,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12367,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":32339,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":23566,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":34390,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":25530,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":35685,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":21603,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30652,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":21610,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":21611,"skillpoints_in_skill":2304000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30651,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12211,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":25718,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":25719,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":24242,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":40572,"skillpoints_in_skill":3072000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":40573,"skillpoints_in_skill":543059,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33407,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3435,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3350,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":41409,"skillpoints_in_skill":452549,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33001,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":25739,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":26252,"skillpoints_in_skill":90510,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":26253,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":26254,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":26255,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":26256,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":26257,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":26258,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":26259,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":26260,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":26261,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":32918,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12441,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12442,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12485,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":21667,"skillpoints_in_skill":1792000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":21668,"skillpoints_in_skill":1792000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3453,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3441,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30540,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11433,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11207,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":32797,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11441,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11442,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":32435,"skillpoints_in_skill":316784,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11446,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11448,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":24764,"skillpoints_in_skill":3072000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11453,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11454,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11455,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3416,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":3,"skill_id":27936,"skillpoints_in_skill":80000,"trained_skill_level":3},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12484,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":16069,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12486,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12487,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33399,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":19921,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":16591,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20312,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":25810,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":25811,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":21718,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":28879,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11083,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":28880,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3300,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3301,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3302,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":32999,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33000,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3305,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3306,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3307,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3308,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3309,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3310,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":37615,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3312,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":20209,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20210,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":20211,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3316,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3317,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3318,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3319,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":24312,"skillpoints_in_skill":3584000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":24313,"skillpoints_in_skill":633568,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":3322,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":3323,"skillpoints_in_skill":90510,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3324,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3325,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3326,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3327,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3328,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3329,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":27906,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3331,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3332,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3333,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3334,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":2,"skill_id":25863,"skillpoints_in_skill":4243,"trained_skill_level":2},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3336,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":11529,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3338,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3339,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20314,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":1,"skill_id":3341,"skillpoints_in_skill":1000,"trained_skill_level":1},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3342,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3348,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3349,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":22806,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":22807,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":22808,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":22809,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3354,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3355,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":3,"skill_id":3356,"skillpoints_in_skill":16000,"trained_skill_level":3},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3357,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3358,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":3,"skill_id":3359,"skillpoints_in_skill":24000,"trained_skill_level":3},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3351,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":4385,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":2,"skill_id":3363,"skillpoints_in_skill":1941,"trained_skill_level":2},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11569,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":3,"skill_id":3368,"skillpoints_in_skill":16000,"trained_skill_level":3},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":21802,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":21803,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":3373,"skillpoints_in_skill":316784,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11566,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":19759,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":19760,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":19761,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":20213,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3380,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11574,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":19767,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":3385,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":3386,"skillpoints_in_skill":45255,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11579,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12092,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12093,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3352,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12095,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12096,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3393,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3394,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":3395,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33092,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":19766,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33094,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33095,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33096,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33097,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30538,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30539,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":11084,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3405,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":3406,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3418,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30544,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30545,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":3410,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3411,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3412,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3413,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30550,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30551,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30552,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30553,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30554,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20315,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3420,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3421,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3422,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":34533,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":35680,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3425,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3426,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":4411,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3428,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":29029,"skillpoints_in_skill":633568,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3430,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3431,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3432,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":3388,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3434,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3303,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3436,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3437,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":3,"skill_id":3438,"skillpoints_in_skill":16000,"trained_skill_level":3},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3439,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":1,"skill_id":3440,"skillpoints_in_skill":1000,"trained_skill_level":1},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3304,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3442,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":3,"skill_id":25235,"skillpoints_in_skill":8000,"trained_skill_level":3},{"active_skill_level":2,"skill_id":3444,"skillpoints_in_skill":2829,"trained_skill_level":2},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":20342,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":22761,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3449,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3450,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3451,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3452,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33002,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3454,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3455,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3456,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3392,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":3,"skill_id":3361,"skillpoints_in_skill":24000,"trained_skill_level":3},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11572,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":40328,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12098,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":23950,"skillpoints_in_skill":2048000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3402,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33091,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":3396,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3311,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33093,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33699,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12201,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12202,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12203,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12204,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":11584,"skillpoints_in_skill":768000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12206,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12207,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":12208,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12209,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12210,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3315,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12212,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12213,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12214,"skillpoints_in_skill":226275,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30537,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30532,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":20212,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30650,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":41403,"skillpoints_in_skill":452549,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":41404,"skillpoints_in_skill":452549,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30653,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":3433,"skillpoints_in_skill":135765,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":28609,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":25538,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":3403,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":3387,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":28615,"skillpoints_in_skill":1024000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":25544,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":12205,"skillpoints_in_skill":362039,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":24311,"skillpoints_in_skill":3584000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":33098,"skillpoints_in_skill":1536000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":41410,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3320,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":19922,"skillpoints_in_skill":1280000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3321,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":21071,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":24314,"skillpoints_in_skill":633568,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":0,"skill_id":13278,"skillpoints_in_skill":0,"trained_skill_level":0},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":3551,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":24571,"skillpoints_in_skill":452549,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":3,"skill_id":3443,"skillpoints_in_skill":8000,"trained_skill_level":3},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30546,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":28656,"skillpoints_in_skill":2560000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":24562,"skillpoints_in_skill":633568,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30547,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":27902,"skillpoints_in_skill":512000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":28073,"skillpoints_in_skill":181020,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":24568,"skillpoints_in_skill":452549,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30548,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":28667,"skillpoints_in_skill":2560000,"trained_skill_level":5},{"active_skill_level":4,"skill_id":24572,"skillpoints_in_skill":452549,"trained_skill_level":4},{"active_skill_level":5,"skill_id":30549,"skillpoints_in_skill":256000,"trained_skill_level":5}]
```

Would be kind if somebody has ideas for this.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula solution is certainly quite possible. Assuming your data is in A1, in B1:

```
=transpose(split(A1,"}"))
```

In C1 and copied down to suit:

```
=SPLIT(substitute(substitute(B1,":",""),",",""),""")")
```

then a little simple tidying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the JSON.  You don't say what language you use or anything like that, but you can start here for an explanation of the format and find the appropriate tool to parse it: https://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is a Json file. And the objects in this all have the same properties. It can thus be easily transformed to CSV, or even Excel.

You can search for a Json to CSV conversion tool, or just use an online tool. I tried this one here with your content and it looks fine:
http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

Comment: Is a function or formula existing to do that in gdocs or do i have to convert this outside from my spreadsheet anyways?